# Why can't the OR operation "||" replace the ternary operator "? :" in this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

The following code works in a browser:

```
var event = event || window.event; 
var eTarget = event.target || event.srcElement; 
var eTargetId = eTarget.id;
```

When I change it to

```
var eTargetId = event.target ? event.target.id : event.srcElement.id;
```

it works, too.

When I change the code to

```
var eTargetId = event.target.id || event.srcElement.id;
```

it doesn't work in IE 678. I get the following error:

> SCRIPT5007:Object expected.

Why is this happening?

Comment: The third example is different from first two examples.

Comment: You need to learn about the existential accessor operator which doesn't exist in ES.

Comment: The existential accessor operator is also known as the "safe navigation operator". It means "return null if the base object reference is null, else return this specific property of the base object."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't attempt to read a property if you haven't checked the base value is really an object, not null.

Usually one would do

```
var eTargetId = event.target && event.target.id || event.srcElement.id;
```

Or, if it's possible for the event target to not have an ID,

```
var eTargetId = event.target && event.target.id
                || event.srcElement && event.srcElement.id
                || "";
```

Comment: Your examples are correct but your first line is confusing - it's not the property "id" being null that causes a problem. You can read a null property without an error. The problem is when you try to treat "target" like an object when it is null. So, more accurately, "don't attempt to read a property if you haven't checked _the object_ exists."

Comment: @Niall Thanks, I meant the base value, not the property value, yes.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek The last code handles the case `event.target` exists and `event.target.id` is the empty string. Not the `srcElement`, that's not problematic.

Comment: @Oriol sorry, I must have misunderstood the intent.

Answer (score 15):

This is likely happening because `event.target` is null but `event` is not. Your first two attempts use short-circuiting to prevent further evaluation if `event.target` is null.

Answer (score 3):

Evaluate `event`, `event.target` and `event.srElement` first

```
var eTargetId = ((event = event || window.event) 
                && (eTargetId = event.target || event.srcElement)
                && eTargetId["id"]) || void 0;
```